# Implementation of the Selection Sort Algorithm

Tags: python, algorithm, comparative-review

I have tried to implement the Selection Sort Algorithm in two different ways, and I was just wondering if that is considered to be a valid implementation of that algorithm. Would that be also considered an efficient implementation of the algorithm, or are there different and more efficient ways?

Here are my implementations:

Implementation Attempt #1

```
def selection_sort(L: List[int]) -> List[int]:
    for i in range(len(L) - 1):
        j = i
        smallest_num = L[i]
        while j < len(L) - 1:
            if smallest_num > L[j + 1]:
                smallest_num = L[j + 1]
            j += 1
        L[L.index(smallest_num)], L[i] = L[i], L[L.index(smallest_num)]
    return L
```

Implementation Attempt #2

```
def selection_sort(L: List[int]):
    for i in range(len(L) - 1):
        j = i
        while j < len(L) - 1:
            swap_min(L, i)
            j += 1
    return L

def swap_min(L: List[int], n: int) -> None:
    smallet_num = min(L[n:])
    sm_indx = L.index(smallet_num)
    L[n], L[sm_indx] = L[sm_indx], L[n]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The use of `L.index(smallest_num)` makes neither of these implementations valid. Using the input list `[1, 0, 1, 0, 1]` as an example, both of your implementations give `[1, 1, 0, 0, 1]` as their result, and this is clearly not sorted correctly.

The reason your algorithm doesn't work on this input is that it contains duplicate elements, so the `.index` method doesn't always return the index you want it to; as the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#common-sequence-operations) says, the `.index` method returns the index of the *first occurrence* of the given value. That will not always be the index of the occurrence you want to find; sometimes, that index is in the "already-sorted" part of the list, so you end up swapping things back there where they don't belong.

A correct implementation of selection sort should search for the index of the minimum element in just the unsorted part of the list.

Comment: Thanks a lot! How about this implementation? https://pastebin.com/CzQ4vEfs

Comment: Looks better, but you'll have to test it.

Answer (score 0):

Your attempts lack [docstrings](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0257/#what-is-a-docstring).

Using [common sequence operations](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#common-sequence-operations) is a nice touch - if only there was a
`index_min = min_index(iterable, *[, key, default])` or a
`min, index = min_index(iterable, *[, key, default])`.

Why use `for i in range()`, but an open coded inner `while`-loop?

In Attempt #1, you keep just one piece of information about the `smallest_num` when a new one is found. If that was the index, you wouldn't have to re-discover it (let alone twice) - at the cost of an indexed access every time you need the value.
Why, in the inner loop, add one to `j` in more than one place?

```
for j in range(i+1, len(L)):
    if L[j] < smallest_num:
        smallest_num = L[j]
        smallest_index = j
```

In Attempt #2, what do you expect the second time `swap_min(L, i)` gets executed?
You don't use `j` in the inner loop. If it was `index = L.index(smallest_num, n)`, `index == n` after the first call - no need for an explicit inner loop at all.